# Create Android Project Folder Using Command Line in mac

Tags: java, android, gradle, command-line, android-project-template

Hello Android Developers,

I know from Android SDK , JDK and Gradle, we can create APK using command line but we still create project folder through Android Studio or other IDEs.

Can someone help, how to create android project folder using command line in mac?

Comment: AFAIK there is no command-line option for this anymore in the Android SDK.

Comment: so need IDE at least at first to create project structure? Once project structure is created , APK can  be build from command line.

Comment: Correct. You can also write your own tool to create a project from the command line. Everything of relevance for building a project consists of text files.